# DNN Cannot access POST method in DNN Api Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, dotnetnuke

My GET method **WORKS** fine when I use the url logged in as SuperUser like this(I get the name of the first user pulled from the DB):

> http://localhost/DesktopModules/AAAA_MyChatServer/API/ChatApi/GetMessage

But I cannot access the POST method in the same controller either using AJAX from view or just by entering the url (post method doesnt get hit/found):

> http://localhost/DesktopModules/AAAA_MyChatServer/API/ChatApi/SendMessage

And also this fails as well:

```
$('#sendChat').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var user = '@Model.CurrentUserInfo.DisplayName';
                    var message = $('#chatBoxReplyArea').val();
                    var url = '/DesktopModules/AAAA_MyChatServer/API/ChatApi/SendMessage';

                    $.post(url, { user: user, message: message }, function (data) {
                    }).done(function () {


                    });
                });
```

The Error message is:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/DesktopModules/AAAA_MyChatServer/API/ChatApi/SendMessage'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'ChatApi' that matches the name 'SendMessage'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

And sometimes:

> "The controller does not support GET method"

even though I do have both a GET and a POST there and the GET works. What am I missing?

I have made a routing class in my DNN project:

```
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;

namespace AAAA.MyChatServer
{
    public class RouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
    {
        public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
        {
            mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("MyChatServer", "default", "{controller}/{action}", new[] { "AAAA.MyChatServer.Services" });

        }
    }
}
```

I added a DNN Api Controller in folder Services of my project named AAAA.MyChatServer:

```
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace AAAA.MyChatServer.Services
{
    [DnnAuthorize(StaticRoles = "SuperUser")]
    public class ChatApiController : DnnApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]           
        public HttpResponseMessage GetMessage()
        {
            ChatServerManager csm = new ChatServerManager();

            var users = csm.GetAllUsers();

            var user = users.FirstOrDefault().Name;
            return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, user);
        }


        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage SendMessage(string toUser, string message)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to call a POST method in a DNN WebAPI: with parameters and with an object. If you use parameters, as you have in your SendMessage method, those parameter values need to be delivered via the Query String.

On the other hand, creating an object and sending that with your call to the WebAPI method can handle a great many more scenarios and is arguably a better way of handling any POST method (as it hides those values from prying eyes, making the call more difficult to counterfeit). To handle this, you can remove the parameters from your SendMessage method and instead interrogate the HttpContext.Current.Request object within your method. The object you created `{ user: user, message: message }` will be nestled in there somewhere.

As it is written in your example, your object was sailing past your parameters like two ships in the night.

I've only just figured this out myself, and I don't have all the understanding I need yet, but hopefully this will help you along your way. Here are some articles I referenced in my quest to use cURL to upload a file to my DNN WebAPI:

- https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/134676/getting-started-with-dotnetnuke-services-framework
- https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/144400/webapi-tips
- [How To Accept a File POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post)
- https://forums.asp.net/t/2104884.aspx?Uploading+a+file+using+webapi+C+
- https://talkdotnet.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/dotnetnuke-webapi-helloworld-example-part-one/comment-page-1/
- http://dnnmodule.com/Article/ArticleDetail/tabid/111/ArticleId/511/Dotnetnuke-7-0-WebAPI-Tips.aspx
- [How to post file using Curl in WebApi in Asp.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165858/how-to-post-file-using-curl-in-webapi-in-asp-net-mvc)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your Web Api for SendMessage contain 2 parameter, so it should POST in query string :
http://localhost/DesktopModules/AAAA_MyChatServer/API/ChatApi/SendMessage?touser=john&message=hello

if you want to POST it using data of object, you need to make the Web Service parameter as object model

Also your javascript parameter is different from the Web Service, as it use "toUser"